# My father's gift on Christmas!

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

I bought my father a gift for Christmas and wrote a riddle for him to solve, but I thought I'd let you guys solve it first :D

> I have caps that I cannot wear
>
> You can enter without a care
>
> Search for an exit, you will not find
>
> But, I have space and an escape you're not confined
>
> If you don't want to play we can come to an end
>
> Send me home I won't contend
>
> Though I have control you're in command
>
> I'll patiently wait for my times are at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it

> a keyboard?

I have caps that I cannot wear

> Caps Lock

You can enter without a care

> Enter key

Search for an exit, you will not find
But, I have space and an escape you're not confined

> Space and Esc keys

If you don't want to play we can come to an end

> End key

Send me home I won't contend

> Home key

Though I have control you're in command

> Control.. or command on Macs

I'll patiently wait for my times are at hand.

> "*" on num pad?

Comment: Correct.  It's a bit simple, but fun to solve none the less.  And for what it's worth it's a wireless Bluetooth keyboard so you can connect to mobile devices (:

Comment: Ooh cool! I wasn't sure if it was real or not, I'm used to the solutions here being.. not actual presents, haha.

Comment: Ahh, well I thought it would give a little spice to the present to make it a bit better ( :