# A pot as a present?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

A bit before Christmas I wrote a riddle titled [My father's gift on Christmas!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47026/my-fathers-gift-on-christmas)  It wasn't my most popular riddle, but it was a real gift and he enjoyed solving it before opening it.

Now my friends birthday is coming up in 6 days and I decided to write him a riddle as well!

> Here's the deal
>
> I have chips and a pot
>
> Though no cookies or a pan
>
> I have one shoe with no sock
>
> And you don't like others seeing you hold my hand

What's the gift?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are ...

> **A poker set**

Here's the deal

> Alluding to dealing of cards

I have chips and a pot

> Poker is played with chips, and antes go into "the pot".  The poker set will come with the chips, though there's no actual physical thing called "a pot" that would come with a poker set, so this part isn't entirely clear.

Though no cookies or a pan

> Nope

I have one shoe with no sock

> The cards are dealt from the "shoe", the set of card decks being played with.  A good poker set probably includes the (vaguely shoe-shaped) container the cards are loaded into after being shuffled, from which cards can easily be dealt. No socks needed.

And you don't like others seeing you hold my hand

> Not entirely clear on what you're after here.  Perhaps, like "Here's the deal", this is just another allusion to hands of poker, or to poker players' hands of cards; but where a riddle speaks of itself in the first person, any use of first person should reference the same solution to the riddle, so I don't know what "my" is doing here.

Comment: The "hand" is what you call all the cards you hold in your hands. and you don't want other people to see your "hand".

Comment: Hole cards are also called hold cards. [Texas Hold 'em Poker](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_'em)

Comment: Sure, but then it gets confusing what "my" is.  You'd expect it to be the gift, not something that is part of a game played using that gift.  It's disconcerting when bits of a riddle which should point to a particular object don't point to a single thing, but rather to random things generally associated with a given subject.

Comment: Well your answer is correct and I think your comment about my last line is also something I should learn from.  I may edit that line a bit